# Search function using combo box,text box and list view

Tags: database, vb.net

[image]i have a few error. i have a search function from the database. when i run the project, and click the SEARCH button to view in the listview, the popup message out called "Incorrect syntax near "CONCAT". here the code for CONCAT

```
Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT Room_Code, Room_Type, Room_No, Room_Price, Room_Status, No_of_Occupancy" & _
                                    "FROM Room" & _
                                    "WHERE" & colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & "LIKE CONCAT ('%', @valueName, '%')"
```

here full code for SEARCH function

```
Private Sub Search()

    ListViewRoom.Items.Clear()

    Dim item As New ListViewItem
    Dim _isFound As Boolean = False

    Dim colName() As String = {"Room_Code", "Room_Type", "Room_No", "Room_Price", "Room_Status", "No_of_Occupancy"}

    Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT Room_Code, Room_Type, Room_No, Room_Price, Room_Status, No_of_Occupancy" & _
                                    "FROM Room" & _
                                    "WHERE" & colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & "LIKE CONCAT ('%', @valueName, '%')"

    dbSource = "Data Source=LAILATUL-PC\SERVER;Initial Catalog=HotelManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True"

    Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=LAILATUL-PC\SERVER;Initial Catalog=HotelManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True")

        Using com As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            With com
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = strSqlSearch
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueName", txtSearch.Text)

            End With

            Try
                con.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader

                While dr.Read
                    _isFound = True

                    item = ListViewRoom.Items.Add(dr("Room_Code").ToString)
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Type".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_No".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Price".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Status".ToString))
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr("No_of_Occupancy".ToString))
                End While

                If Not _isFound Then
                    MsgBox("No results found.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using





End Sub
```

I hope u can help me. Tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the CONCAT. just remove it from the SQL and it should work.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT Room_Code, Room_Type, Room_No, Room_Price, Room_Status, No_of_Occupancy" & _
                             "FROM Room" & _
                             "WHERE" & colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & "LIKE '%'+ @valueName +'%'"
```

**Edit #2**

```
Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT Room_Code, Room_Type, Room_No, Room_Price, Room_Status, No_of_Occupancy" & _
                             "FROM Room" & _
                             "WHERE" & colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & "LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
```

And remove the parameter form the SqlCommand.

Comment: it still not work.this is my interface https://www.dropbox.com/s/lafqqpa52hzajz4/Listview%20Room.jpg

Comment: do you still get an exception? if so, what is it?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice there is another change needed. see my edited answer.

Comment: See the part after **Edit #2**

Comment: after i change the code in part two, i still get error. when itry to search "110" for Room_Code the error is "Syntax error near '%110%'

Comment: A space is missing between column name and keyword LIKE.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what is mean?

Comment: colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & "LIKE should be colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & " LIKE

btw, this is probably the reason you got the error in the first place, sorry, I didn't see it before.

Comment: it's mean colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & " LIKE btw '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'" ? Like that?

Comment: What do you mean "btw"? Can you show your current code?

Comment: Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT Room_Code, Room_Type, Room_No, Room_Price, Room_Status, No_of_Occupancy" & _
                             "FROM Room" & _
                             "WHERE" & colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & "LIKE btw '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"

Comment: Ok, now I understand. the btw I wrote is not a part of the SQL, it's a part of the comment. Your SQL should look like this: Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT Room_Code, Room_Type, Room_No, Room_Price, Room_Status, No_of_Occupancy " & _ "FROM Room " & _ "WHERE " & colName(cboSearch.SelectedIndex) & " LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"

Comment: i also have problem when to show the search data. in the interface, in the left side have a numbering. but the numbering does not work properly. this the coding :

Comment: item.Text = no

item = ListViewRoom.Items.Add(item.Text = no)
item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Code".ToString))
item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Type".ToString))
item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_No".ToString))
                        item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Price".ToString))
                        item.SubItems.Add(dr("Room_Status".ToString))
                        item.SubItems.Add(dr("No_of_Occupancy".ToString))End While

Comment: Please search the questions or open a new question about it. you'll get a much better chance at getting the correct answer because a lot more people is going to read it.